# Adding Switches by using button - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase

Im new on Android Studio. I want my button to add a new switch on screen. What should I do?

Comment: pls show some snippet what u did where u stuck , don't ask question without code

Comment: bro I didnt stuck anywhere. my code is working fine. But I dont know how to edit my xml file from mainactivity.

Comment: search "android add views dinamically"

Comment: why,  u want to edit xml from mainactivity when you can direactly edit it, xml inside layout folder

Answer (score 1):

**For adding a switch on Android Studio you can follow these steps:**

**Step 1:** Create Switch in XML Layout File

**Step 2:** Create Switch Control in Activity File

**Step 3:** Handle Switch Click Events

**Step 4:** Follow The Given Android Switch Control Attributes

**Have a look here for more details:**

[Check this firstly](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/android/android-switch-on-off-button-with-examples)

[Check this secondly](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch)